# Previewing the class or function definition source code in the interactive shell

Tags: python, shell

Is it possible to access a source code of the imported class or funciton while using interactive shell like IDLE Shell or Linux python?

In example, I wish that it was possible to do the following:

```
from myClasses import MyClass

#this
print MyClass.__source__ 
#or that
source(MyClasss)

# would result in:
def MyClass(object):
    pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from myClasses import MyClass
import inspect

source = inspect.getsource(MyClass)
print source

#class MyClass(object):
#    pass
```